# Include HTML markup as plain text in a webpage

Tags: html, html-parsing

What's the proper way of displaying valid HTML as plain text in a webpage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    <pre>
      <code>
        <!-- As seen on stackoverflow.com, and it's correct -->
        <p class="inception">valid HTML</p>
      </code>
    </pre>
```

Comment: And [encode HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/B7448/) so you can see the affected markup. For example, PHP has [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).